# Cannot open Aurelia site in EDGE

Tags: webpack, aurelia, microsoft-edge

Having a strange issue with Microsoft Edge not loading my Aurelia site.  I've googled for hours with no luck. Microsoft's only solution is to clear cache or do an sfc /scannow. If I have developer tools open, the page attempts to load, but after a few seconds I get the same result.

I've published the site here: https://jbockle.github.io/aurelia-json-schema-form/

I'm getting the following error redirect:

> This page is having a problem loading
>
> We tried to load this page for you a few times, but there is still a
> problem with this site. We know you have better things to do than to
> watch this page reload over and over again so try coming back to this
> page later.

I need to confirm that its not just me having this issue, and if you have any tips to address this issue.

My project is open source here: https://github.com/jbockle/aurelia-json-schema-form

Comment: also, devtools closes automatically on the redirect, I don't see any errors appear beforehand

Comment: Fails to load on my Edge too, so it's not a local issue on your PC. I suggest that you start with the most simple Aurelia app that does nothing more than displaying an empty page. If it works then you know the issue is somewhere in your code. In this case repeat the test, adding more code each time, until you nail the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem ended up being an `<input type="range">` element with `placeholder.bind` attribute I copied from my other template.  For some reason, it caused the microsoftedgecp.exe to crash. Removing the attribute fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using media query -ms-viewport in your project?

When I try to open your page in Edge, I got warning below.

[image]

You can try to remove it from your project may help you to solve this issue. It's looks like -ms-viewport is not supported by Edge anymore.

If you run the page with Chrome then page get loads but there is also 404 error get generated in the console.